# Increment hour field by 5 (UTC to EST format)

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

I have a file with thousands of records. Each line should have one or more date-time fields in UTC format.

I need to convert the date and time field to EST format: adding +5 to the hour field, and if it becomes greater than 24, the date should also change.

For example:

Input:

```
123456|2016-03-10T14:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T23:30:25.000

654321|2016-03-10T20:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-11T04:30:25.000
```

Output should be:

```
123456|2016-03-10T19:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T14:30:25.000

654321|2016-03-11T01:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T19:30:25.000
```

This is what I have tried:

```
# cat f
123456|2016-03-10T14:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T23:30:25.000 654321|2016-03-10T20:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-11T04:30:25.000
# awk 'BEGIN {FS = "T";; OFS="T" } $2+=4,$3+=5' f
123456|2016-03-10T18T28 654321|2016-03-10T24T9
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You seem to have forgotten to post a [mcve] of the code that isn't working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but [so] is not a code-writing service. You'll have to demonstrate some effort if you expect to receive help here.

Comment: I am new and i dont have much knowledge on scripting but i tried below one which is changing the hour  field but data is missing and i am not sure how to calculate the date if hr goes beyond 24

# cat f
123456|2016-03-10T14:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T23:30:25.000

654321|2016-03-10T20:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-11T04:30:25.000

# awk 'BEGIN {FS = "T";; OFS="T" } $2+=4,$3+=5' f
123456|2016-03-10T18T28
654321|2016-03-10T24T9

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your calculation is wrong. You convert from UTC to EST by subtracting five hours, not by adding five hours (assuming that by "EST" you mean US Eastern Standard Time).

Here's how I'd do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S';
my $dp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern   => $fmt,
  time_zone => 'UTC',
);

while (<DATA>) {
  s/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/change_time($1)/eg;
  print;
}

sub change_time {
  my $time = shift;
  my $dt = $dp->parse_datetime($time);
  $dt->set_time_zone("EST");
  return $dt;
}

__DATA__
123456|2016-03-10T14:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T23:30:25.000

654321|2016-03-10T20:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-11T04:30:25.000
```

The output from running this is:

```
123456|2016-03-10T09:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T18:30:25.000

654321|2016-03-10T15:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-10T23:30:25.000
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{ $2=upd($2); $6=upd($6); print }
function upd(dt,        a) {
    split(dt,a,/[.]/)
    gsub(/[-T:]/," ",a[1])
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",mktime(a[1])+5*60*60) "." a[2]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
123456|2016-03-10T19:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-11T04:30:25.000
654321|2016-03-11T01:30:25.000|abcd|efdgh|1245|2016-03-11T09:30:25.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Life is too short for doing date and time calculations by hand. So use a language that includes modules for time handling. Based on your choice of tags I would chose Perl and the DateTime module.

So extract the date field and then create a DateTime object to do the calculations:

```
use DateTime;
my $date = '2016-03-10T23:30:25.000'
if ($date =~ /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/) {
    my $dt = DateTime->new(year => $1, month => $2, day => $3,
                           hour => $4, minute => $5, second => $6,
                           time_zone => 'UTC');

    $dt->set_time_zone("EST");
    $date = $dt->ymd . "T" . $dt->hms;
} else {
    die "invalid date";
}
```

This would take care of all the corner cases where it is not just offsetting with 5 hours.

Yes, I know that DateTime is not the fastest solution. But unless proven otherwise I think it should perform well enough.

Comment: Small typo - `time_zone`, not `time_sone`. And I think that DateTime::Format::Strptime will make this a little easier - no need to parse out all of the individual bits from the timestamp.